# how to fix a block cipher implementation error

Tags: java, encryption

When decrypting, I get in the correct initial state only every third line

I break the source text into blocks of 64 bits, then do the replacement of the bits among themselves, but the outputs, when decrypting, the text is different from the original. Only every third row is true

```
byte[] bin = text.getBytes("UTF8");
    ArrayList<Byte> binary = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for (int i=0; i<bin.length; i++){
        binary.add(bin[i]);
    }
    if(binary.size()%64!=0){
        while (binary.size()%64 !=0){
            binary.add(bin[0]);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Byte> list =new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<binary.size(); i++){
        if (i%64!=0){
            list.add(binary.get(i));
        }
        else{
               for(int l = 0; l < list.size()/2; l++) {
                    if (list.get(l) >= list.get(list.size()-1-l)) {
                        list.set(l, list.get(list.size()-1-l));
                        list.set(list.size()-1-l, list.get(l));
                }
 }

            for(int p = 0; p < list.size(); p++) {
                itogovy.add(list.get(p));
            }
            list.clear();
        }

    }
    byte[] result = new byte[itogovy.size()];
    for (int v=0; v<itogovy.size(); v++ ){
        result[v]=itogovy.get(v);
    }
    sun.misc.BASE64Encoder unsupportedEncoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
    sunEncoded = unsupportedEncoder.encode(result);
    System.out.println(sunEncoded);
```

decryption, respectively

```
 byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(ss);
    ArrayList<Byte> binary = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for (int i=0; i<dec.length; i++){               
        binary.add(dec[i]);
    }
    ArrayList<Byte> list =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Byte> itogov =new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<binary.size(); i++){
        if (i%64!=0){
            list.add(binary.get(i));
        }
        else{
            for(int l = 0; l > list.size()/2; l++) {
                if (list.get(l) <= list.get(list.size()-1-l)) {
                    list.set(l, list.get(list.size()-1-l));
                    list.set(list.size()-1-l, list.get(l));

                }
            }
            for (int q=0; q<list.size(); q++){
                itogov.add(list.get(q));
            }
            list.clear();
        }
    }
    while (itogov.get(itogov.size()-1)==itogov.get(itogov.size()-2)){
        itogov.remove(itogov.size()-1);
    }
    itogov.remove(itogov.size()-1);
    byte[] result = new byte[itogov.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < itogov.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = itogov.get(i);
    }
    //System.out.println((byte) k.toString().length()/10);
    String sunDecoder = new String(result, "UTF8");
    System.out.println(sunDecoder);
```

I will be grateful for the help

Comment: You will get a better response if you name your block-cipher.

Comment: Unrelated, but do you really want to use `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` instead of the standard `java.util.Base64` class